# Vertx web routes and Reactive Pg Client issue in Quarkus

Tags: vert.x, reactive, quarkus

The application is based on the following stack:

- Quarkus 1.5.0
- Extensions: vertx-web, reactive-pgclient

The complete codes is [here](https://github.com/hantsy/quarkus-sample/tree/master/vertx-routes).

I created a Router by `@Observes Router`.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class RoutesObserver {

    @Inject PostsHandlers handlers;

    public void route(@Observes Router router) {
        router.get("/posts").produces("application/json").handler(handlers::getAll);
        router.post("/posts").consumes("application/json").handler(handlers::save);
        router.get("/posts/:id").produces("application/json").handler(handlers::get);
        router.put("/posts/:id").consumes("application/json").handler(handlers::update);
        router.delete("/posts/:id").handler(handlers::delete);

        router.get("/hello").handler(rc -> rc.response().end("Hello from my route"));
    }

}
```

And extracted the handlers into a standalone bean.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
class PostsHandlers {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger(PostsHandlers.class.getSimpleName());

    PostRepository posts;

    ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Inject
    public PostsHandlers(PostRepository posts, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.posts = posts;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    public void getAll(RoutingContext rc) {
        this.posts.findAll().thenAccept(
                data -> rc.response()
                        .write(toJson(data))
                        .end()

        );
    }
   //... other methods.

}
```

And the PostRepository used the Java 8 `CompletionStage` API.

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class PostRepository {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostRepository.class);

    private final PgPool client;

    @Inject
    public PostRepository(PgPool _client) {
        this.client = _client;
    }

    public CompletionStage<List<Post>> findAll() {
        return client.query("SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id ASC")
                .execute()
                .thenApply(rs -> StreamSupport.stream(rs.spliterator(), false)
                        .map(this::from)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList())
                );
    }
```

And when I ran this application and tried to access the `/posts`. It is frozen and no response printed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `write` method, you need to set (beforehand) the `content-length` header.

There are a several approaches to handle this:

1. You can use `.end(toJson(data))` instead of `write(...).end()` - it will computed the length automatically
2. You can use `.putHeader("transfer-encoding", "chunked")` and you `write(...).end()` - if you plan to retrieve multiple results, it's interesting as it writes each chunk to the client one by one, avoiding sending a large payload in one go
3. you can set the `content-length` as in:

```java
String result = toJson(data);
rc.response()
   .putHeader("content-length", Long.toString(result.length()))
   .write(result)
   .end();
```